# maven selenium serenity bdd open index.html report automatically after test

Tags: java, maven, selenium, intellij-idea, serenity-bdd

I have been searching but haven't found an answer. Is there anyway of opening the report index.html automatically after running a test in the terminal or in intellij? Im pretty new to this stuff. Thanks for any help.

Set up

-http://www.thucydides.info/#/
-junit
-selenium

Thank you for any future help.

Here is a copy of my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <serenity.version>1.0.47</serenity.version>
    <serenity.maven.version>1.1.29-rc.1</serenity.maven.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.52.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.18</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    <include>**/When*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>auto-clean</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>/target/site/serenity</directory>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>index</report>
                        <report>summary</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding:

```
@AfterClass
```

directly to your Runner class and adding method with:

```
getDriver().get("YourReportPath")
```